# Dompdf UTF8 decode Issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, dompdf

I Generate Tamil Article in PDF using DOMPDF in Laravel.

In my View I defined Charset as Following :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

but generate as PDF following :

[image]

Controller Code :

```
$memberDatas=Members::find($id);

$pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf/pension', compact('memberDatas'));

return $pdf->download('NALA00-'.$memberDatas->id.'.pdf');
```

**My Dompdf Version is 0.8.0**

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0",
```

Comment: please show your `$memberDatas` and the pdf view. In my project, I am using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` too and working well

Comment: @brobrobrobrobro pdf view code : https://codeshare.io/2BMKbL  $memberDatas code is already showed in question details.

Comment: Unless you're in a very strict environment like shared hosting to deploy your code, using dompdf is not a good idea. You should be using wkhtmltopdf instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Tamil? UTF-8 not supppot Tamil.
I haven't tested yet, but you can try use `charset=x-iscii-ta` or any charset that support your character.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I tried another package and it's Working.

You can check [**Package**](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) and [**Git repo**](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy).

**Composer command**

`composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy`

Thanks for all of you..